# Android land / port layout structure not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have included the following folders within my project:

```
layout    
layout-land/
layout-port/
```

I placed the my main.axml file in all of them, with a couple of tweaks to the UI of course. But when I change the orientation on the device, noting happens.

I'm doing basically the same as this tutorial, but I'm making use of Xamarin and Visual Studio: http://www.how-to-develop-android-apps.com/how-to-make-a-landscape-layout-in-android/

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong?! Could someone please assist?

Comment: `layout` and `layout-port/` having same behavior only.. Why you're using separately.

Comment: anything in your configChange in your manifest ?

Comment: By "nothing happens", do you mean that the screen doesn't rotate? If that's true, you need to unlock auto-rotation and not force any orientation in the activity code/manifest (which is the default)

Comment: hmmm, didn't know that. I do now.. Still doesn't explain why the layout-land doesn't work?!

Comment: Nothing Dear just remove the layout-port folder and put this xml file in default layout then see it`s properly work.

Comment: @PedroLoureiro - no, the screen rotates, but the 'correct' UI does not get loaded. In this case, the **land** does not show. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: I'm busy removing the folder layout-port and running my test again....

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: Okay, removed the _port_ folder ... this did not change anything, and I made some notable changes in the UI.

Comment: what changes r u done this is already work dear

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: Could you please rephrase your question / statement? Not really sure what you just said?!

Comment: @njzk2 - I have made no changes within my manifest file with regards to orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so basically I had a folder called `layout-normal`. This caused the `layout-land` to be ignored for some or other reason. I removed the folder from the project and it worked!